# Pass DateTimePicker Value to a stored procedure C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have `DataGridView` and `DateTimePicker` and I want to show data in `DataGridView` based on `DateTimePicker` value.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
create proc Get_Employers_All_Day
    @Date_Day date
as 

SELECT 
    [Employer_ID] as 'رقم الموظف'
    , Employer_Name as 'اسم الموظف'
FROM [dbo].[Come_Out]
inner join Employers 
    on Employers .Epmloyer_ID = Come_Out .Employer_ID 
where 
    Come_Out .Status = '2'
     and Come_Out .Data_Come_Out = @Date_Day
```

Here is the C# code:

```
public void Get_Employers_All_Day(DateTime Date_Day)
{

    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Date_Day", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    param[0].Value = Date_Day;

    DAL.ExecuteCommand("Get_Employers_All_Day", param);
    DAL.Close();

}
```

and the event :

```
private void Frm_Daily_Come_Out_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BL.Employers emp = new BL.Employers();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = emp.Get_Employers_All_Day(dateTimePicker1 .Value );
}
```

The error is:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Answer (score 2):

Your `Get_Employers_All_Day()` method has a return type of `void`, meaning it has no return type.

Modify it to return the data you need. If your `DAL.ExecuteCommand()` returns a `DataTable`, for example, modify it to return that:

```
public DataTable Get_Employers_All_Day(DateTime Date_Day)
{
    ...
    ...

    DataTable result;
    try
    {
        result = DAL.ExecuteCommand("Get_Employers_All_Day", param);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Even if ExecuteCommand() fails, close any open connections
        DAL.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```